# Delete subfolders and files by # of days using Perl

Tags: perl

New to Perl, used only 3 times.  I need to delete files and subfolders from a parent directory when they are over a week old.  I've deleted files before using -M but never worked with subfolders. When I run the details below, no files are deleted from the subfolders and files over a week old exist in the subfolders.  The testing messages show 'myAge' is zero, for ALL files in the subfolders. Not sure what I'm missing. Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

```
msg ("\n");
msg ("Start: \n");


my $parent  = 'C:/temp/XYZ';
my ($par_dir, $sub_dir);

opendir($par_dir, $parent);
msg " parent is $parent \n";

while (my $sub_folders = readdir($par_dir)) {
    next if ($sub_folders =~ /^..?$/);  # skip . and ..

    my $path = $parent . '/' . $sub_folders;

    next unless (-d $path);   # skip anything that isn't a directory
    next unless ( -M $subfolder <  7  );

    msg " subfolder is $sub_folders is old enough to delete \n";

    opendir($sub_dir, $path);
    while (my $file = readdir($sub_dir)) {

    # for testing       
    my $myAge = (-M $file) ;
    msg " age ... $myAge __ file ...  $file\n" ;    

        if ( -M $file >   7  ) {
        msg " going to delete this file...  $file \n";
        } else {
        msg " will keep this file not old enough $file\n";
        }

    }   
    closedir($sub_dir);
}
closedir($par_dir);
```

Comment: Where did the `msg()` function come from?

Comment: Shouldn't `next unless ( -M $subfolder <  7  );` be `next unless ( -M $path <  7  );`? And `-M $file` be `-M "$path/$file"`? [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) only returns a file or directory name (without its parent directory).

Comment: msg () writes to a log file, sorry for not referencing that earlier

Comment: changing $subfolder to $path and changing  $file to $path/$file, doesn't seem to allow the script to continue, the " subfolder is ..." message never displays and no files or folders are deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is really only the 3rd time you use Perl, then *Congratulations!* But there are some issues in your code:

- **Always** add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to your code. This will warn (beyond others) about
  undefined variables and eliminate common errors.
- You had a typo with `$sub_folders` vs. `$subfolder`. `use strict;` and `use warnings;` would have shown that.
- The return values of `readdir` do NOT contain the parent directory. The [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) say:

  > If you're planning to filetest the return values out of a readdir, you'd better 
  >   prepend the directory in question. Otherwise, because we didn't chdir there, 
  >   it would have been testing the wrong file.

  I assume that's exactly what happened here.

I changed your code a bit by prepending the directory to the filenames and it seems to work now.
I also wrote a `msg` function that simply `print`s the given parameters. You would omit that
if you have a "real" `msg` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub msg
{
    print @_;
}

msg("\n");
msg("Start: \n");

my $parent = 'C:/temp/XYZ';
my ( $par_dir, $sub_dir );

opendir( $par_dir, $parent ) or die "cannot opendir $parent: $!\n";;
msg " parent is $parent \n";

while ( my $sub_folders = readdir($par_dir) ) {
    next if ( $sub_folders =~ /^..?$/ );    # skip . and ..

    my $path = "$parent/$sub_folders";

    next unless ( -d $path );               # skip anything that isn't a directory
    next unless ( -M $path < 7 );

    msg " subfolder is $sub_folders is old enough to delete \n";

    opendir( $sub_dir, $path ) or die "cannot opendir $path: $!\n";
    while ( my $file = readdir($sub_dir) ) {

        # for testing
        my $myAge = ( -M "$path/$file" );
        msg " age ... $myAge __ file ...  $path/$file\n";

        if ( -M "$path/$file" > 7 ) {
            msg " going to delete this file...  $path/$file \n";
        } else {
            msg " will keep this file not old enough $path/$file\n";
        }

    }
    closedir($sub_dir);
}
closedir($par_dir);
```

There are some things that can be improved in this code.

1. I wouldn't check the directories for their modification time and drop the `next unless ( -M $path < 7 );`. 
   My impression is that the attributes of directories (size, times) change at will — at least I couldn't
   ever figure out a pattern but perhaps I'm just too dumb for that.
2. To speed up things, the `-X` operator (like `-d`, `-M`, etc.) caches the result of the last file. So instead
   of writing

   ```
   next unless ( -d $path );
   next unless ( -M $path < 7 );
   ```

   you *could* write

   ```
   next unless ( -d $path );
   next unless ( -M _ < 7 ); # the '_' means: get '-M' of $path
   ```

   See [`-X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) for details. Basically `-X` fetches all attributes of a
   given file (like size, type, access time, modification time, etc) at once. If you pass an underscore `_` as the
   filename in subsequent calls, then the results of the previous call (with the real filename) are returned and
   another (expensive) systemcall is saved.
3. The algorithm only considers one directory below the starting directory, i.e. it doesn't work recursively.
   Depending on what you actually want, this might or might not be OK.

Comment: @Fondah You're welcome. Once again: if it was really your 3rd script, then you must have some talent. +1 for showing an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're on a *nix system ..

sometimes it's easier to just call find

```
find /foo/bar/ -type d -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;

find /foo/bar/ -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

will delete all 7 days old (d)irectories or (f)iles

Comment: Nice, but given the `my $parent  = 'C:/temp/XYZ';` in the question plus the _"… in Perl"_ in the header line I assume the OP is searching for a pure Perl solution.

Comment: OK, use module File:Find then. I guess it's "cpanm install file:find" if you have cpan minus installed. (http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)

Comment: File::Find has been part of the Perl core since Perl 5 was first released.  No need to install it.

Comment: I am including  use File::Find;